# Changing HTTP header code in POST response

Tags: apex, httpresponse, post

I've been doing some research on this issue, but I haven't been able to find a solution. I'm trying to return `HTTP 403` after failing to validate some information sent in a `POST` request to Salesforce. I have considered just throwing an exception to get some sort of error code returned, but that doesn't seem like a great way to do it.

I also tried using the `HttpResponse` class, but I'm not exactly sure how to. Doing something like the following yields the obvious error saying the function must return a `String`.

```
if (<some validation fails>) {
        HttpResponse err = new HttpResponse();
        err.setStatusCode(403);
        return err;
}
```

**What's the best way to send a response with a specific HTTP header code through an Apex class?**

Thanks!

**EDIT**

In response to @metadaddy, this is in an Apex class, ie:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myendpoint')

global class MyClass {

    @HttpPost

    global static String doPost() {

        //Do stuff

        //Return something
        return JSON.serialize(retrievedVals);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this in an Apex REST Method or a Visualforce Page?

Comment: @metadaddy this is in an Apex REST method - see my edit please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern where you explicitly update the [RestContext](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_restcontext.htm) allows you to set the status value:

```
@HttpPost
global static void doPost() {

    // Do stuff

    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    if (res == null) {
        res = new RestResponse();
        RestContext.response = res;
    }

    // Return something
    res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(retrievedVals));

    // Set the status
    res.statusCode = 403;
}
```

There is a more complete example [here](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/an-restresource-apex-class-that-returns-multiple-json-formats/).

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed, thank you!